# Rails 3: can't figure out this Actionview Template error, need help please?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm getting an ActionviewTemplate error when trying to POST using an ajax response. The 'create' method keeps looking for the default create.js.erb file but I've specifically pointed to the file it should render.

I tried adding "end and return" to my respond_to blocks but nothing happens.

```
Started POST "/appreciations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-25 13:30:09 -0700
  Processing by AppreciationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T3PeKRaSJSrESFTOCQ7+4LiM4BKaWkcaQ6cXpSqK38k=", "appreciation"=>{"liked_id"=>"75"}, "commit"=>"Like"}
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Completed   in 343ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template appreciations/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", "*/*"], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/iHal/Desktop/WORK/GP/app/views"
```

### Appreciatins controller

```
class AppreciationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

def create
  if params[:liked_id]
    @post = Post.find(params[:appreciation][:liked_id])
    current_user.like!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js  { render :action => "create_like" }
    end
  elsif params[:voted_id]
    @post = Post.find(params[:appreciation][:voted_id])
    current_user.vote!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js  { render :action => "create_vote" }
    end
  elsif params[:thanked_id]
    @post = Post.find(params[:appreciation][:thanked_id])
    current_user.thank!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js  {render :action => 'create_thank'} 
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  if params[:liked_id]
    @post = Appreciation.find(params[:id]).liked
    current_user.unlike!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js { render :action => "destroy_like" }
    end
  elsif params[:vote_id]
    @post = Appreciation.find(params[:id]).voted
    current_user.unvote!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js { render :action => "destroy_vote" }
    end
  elsif params[:thanked_id]
    @post = Appreciation.find(params[:id]).thanked
    current_user.unthank!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js { render :action => "destroy_thank" }
    end
  end
end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params` check is incorrect; `liked_id` is nested within the `:appreciation` hash.

Answer (score 0):

`liked_id` isn't in the top level of params, it's nested in `params[:appreciation]`.  You look for it in the right place in the `find`, but in the `if; elsif` logic you're looking for it as `params[:liked_id]`.

It doesn't exist there, so none of your conditions are running. The action ends without any instruction on what to render, so the default happens.